# Java swt delete/undo for paint commad

Tags: java, shell, graphics, swt, java-canvas

Consider -

```
public class MainCanvas extends Canvas {...}
```

And

```
Display display = new Display();
display = new Display();
myShell = new Shell(display);
myCanvas = new MainCanvas(myShell, SWT.NO);
GC myGC = new GC(myShell);
myGC.fillOval(10,20,30,40) ; //paint shape ..
```

Now I want to delete the shape painted by `myGC.fillOval(10,20,30,40) ;` from the canvas   .

Is there any command to delete the last paint  , or command to clear the canvas ?

Comment: Why not just fill a rectangle covering the whole GC?

Comment: the `javax.swing.undo` provides undo/redo functionality in Swing, not sure of an alternative in SWT

Comment: What you could do is to save the canvas as an image in a stack after each drawing operations, and pop the stack for an undo.

Answer (score 1):

Very good question. I have just started using JAVA SWT and I have encountered the same issue.

The solution I have come up with is to replace the Canvas with a new one, identical one each time I have to empty its contents without affecting anything else.

To this end, I am using the **canvas.dispose()** command and redraw and repack the Shell using **shell.redraw()** and **shell.pack()** so that the window is resized properly. These commands are called from another event, like the press of a button (an Enter button in the example provided below). Also, please note that in the example below I am using a GridLayout (for more information, please refer to http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html) and I am creating a polyline using an array of integers.

```
    myCanvas = new Canvas(shell, SWT.BORDER); // create the initial instance of the Canvas
    gridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true);
    gridData.widthHint = 1100; // set desired width
    gridData.heightHint = 800; // set desired height
    gridData.verticalSpan = 3; // set number of columns it will occupy
    myCanvas.setLayoutData(gridData);


    myEnter_Button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent mainEvent) {
            myCanvas.dispose(); // delete the Canvas
            myCanvas = new Canvas(shell, SWT.BORDER);
            GridData redrawGridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true);
            redrawGridData.widthHint = 1100;
            redrawGridData.heightHint = 800;
            redrawGridData.verticalSpan = 3;
            myCanvas.setLayoutData(redrawGridData);
            shell.redraw();
            shell.pack(); // pack shell again

    myCanvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
                public void paintControl(final PaintEvent event) {
                    // coordinateIntegerArray not displayed in this example
                    event.gc.drawPolyline(coordinateIntegerArray);//draw something

                    }
                }
            });

            myCanvas.redraw();
        }
    });
```

I hope this helped.  If I manage to find a way of exclusively deleting / undoing the last paint object drawn, I'll be sure to let you know.

Cheers!